# how to avoid enviroment variable from resetting in WSL terminal after restart?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, windows-subsystem-for-linux, zshrc

environment variable set (in zsh shell) in WSL disappears after restarting the terminal. I have used

```
export variable_name=variable_value
```

to set environment variable. how should I avoid env variable from resetting after restart.

Comment: Did you add the command in `.zshrc` file?

Comment: oh ok! **thanks!** I add it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added environment variable in .zshrc file after reading comment of [@Biswapriyo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8928481/biswapriyo). 
like this-

`export variable_name=variable_value`
 
and now it works.
 
I think, at every startup, scripts in .zshrc file are ran so this env variable is addded. If you use bash instead of zsh then you may try adding this in .bashrc file or any other rc file.
 You can check if env variable is added or not by 

`printenv`